# Grails spock Testing with File class

Tags: unit-testing, grails, file-io

I have a method that create a file based in a content copied from an another file.
Like below

```
private cloneBaseFile(fileName, ddi, ddd){


    def config = grailsApplication.config.kicksim.fileConstants


    String baseFileContents = new File(config.baseFile).getText('UTF-8')

    def help = handleString("${ddd}.${ddi}")

    baseFileContents = baseFileContents.replaceAll("DDDDDI", help);

    def f1= new File(fileName)
    f1 << baseFileContents

    return fileName
}
```

I'd like to know how to unit test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look to separate out the responsibilities of this method (c.f. [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).  If you haven't got a copy of Robert Martin's book called Clean Code then I'd highly recommend it: his code is a work of art and taught me a lot.

`cloneBaseFile()` is actually doing many things: it's opening a file, getting the contents of the file, doing something (I don't know what) in `handleString()`, replacing the contents of the file with a modified version of its contents and then finally saving the file.

How about (as a starter for 10):

```
private cloneBaseFile(fileName, ddi, ddd){   
    def config = grailsApplication.config.kicksim.fileConstants
    String baseFileContents = getFileContents(config.baseFile)
    baseFileContents = handleFileContents(baseFileContents)
    return createNewFileWithContents(fileName, baseFileContents)
}

String getFileContents(String fileName) {
   String contents = new File(fileName).getText('UTF-8')
   return contents
}

String handleFileContents(String oldContents) {
    def help = handleString("${ddd}.${ddi}")
    return oldContents.replaceAll("DDDDDI", help);
}

String createNewFileWithContents(String newFileName, String newContents) {
    def f1= new File(newFileName)
    f1 << newContents
    return newFileName
}
```

Now you have multiple small methods, each of which can be tested far more easily.  You'll also want to test the `handleString()` method.

Comment: John, thank you for the answer. It makes sense. I'll go for it